# Zenject injection from an existing in scene prefab

Tags: unity, gameobject, dependency-injection

I am trying to use Zenject to automatically inject a reference to a component on a game object that I have in the scene, but can only seem to make the create new component on new object work. Should I be using a prefab installer and if so why can't I just drag the prefab into the prefab installer?

Comment: If you're trying to automatically inject a reference to a component on a game object into another object, maybe you should trying using ZenjectBinding? (see docs)

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured the game object and the component you want to reference, including where each sits in your project/scene hierarchy?